# Install util looks for service on wrong folder

Tags: c#, .net, service, batch-file, installutil

3
I'm trying to install a Windows Service using a batch file, let's call it "setup.bat". Inside the file I have the following commands:

```
"%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\installutil" "MyService.exe"
```

When I excute the batch file (running as administrator on windows7) I get this:

Exception occurred while initializing the installation:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Win
dows\system32\MyService.exe' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot f
ind the file specified.. 
The actual service is located at 
`"SomeRandomLocation\MyService.exe".`
the bat file is 
`"SomeRandomLocation\setup.bat"`

what is going on?  how do I force it to install from my "setup.bat" folder?

**this should work dynamicly. meaning in any folder!**

Comment: Try to add the path to the service: `"%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\installutil" "c:\services\MyService.exe"` in your setup.bat.

Comment: you don't need to shout at us. Don't use ALL CAPS.

Comment: There are two answers and one comment, all saying esentially the same, Windows requires you specify where your file is located. If you don't know where your file is located, then Windows don't neither. If you know the file is located in the same directory than the BAT file, and this is just one possible assumption, there might be other possibilities, then you may extract if from your executing BAT and pass it to Windows in the command line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know anything about the install process. But `%~dp0` will give the absolute path of your running batch file. So if your exe is in the same folder, you could try:

```
"%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\installutil" "%~dp0MyService.exe"
```

Comment: thank you! this solves my problem. I still don't know why installutil went to the system32 folder in the first place and would love to know that but the problem is solved!

Answer (score 1):

If you create a .bat file, then the working directory is based on the location from where you invoked the .bat.  If you created a shortcut to the .bat file, then the working directory is based on the location of the .bat file.  Any relative path in your script is interpreted relative to the working directory.

To avoid changing all your paths. Just issue a `cd C:\Services` at the beginning of your bat file.

Comment: that is not a dynamic solution. it wouldn't work if I change a folder.

Answer (score 1):

For my own usage I created a small .bat file:

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe" %1
```

And now, when I want to install service I just drag .exe file on the .bat. Works perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting working directory to C:\Services?

Answer (score 0):

although this is an old question...

what helped me to solve the issue is to run the installer with logs

For example:

```
"%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\installutil" "MyService.exe" /LogToConsole /ShowCallStack
```

In my case the original error was like yours

> FileNotFoundException

, but in the logs I found

> SecurityException

The solution was to run as administrator

Answer (score -1):

It works for me (of course) - It looks for `MyService.exe` in the containing folder.
`"c:\windows\system32"` is not the location of `installutil`, so perhaps earlier in the batch file the working directory is changed somehow.

Presuming this is not the only command in the batch file:
Try to add `set OLDDIR=%CD%` at the very beginning of the batch file,
And add `chdir /d %OLDDIR%` just before the installutil command, and see if this works.